# The value not changed in the keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following function:

```
formCreated = function (event, data) {  
    console.log(data.formType); // output: 'edit'   

    $('body').on('keydown', function (e) {           
       if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 80) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            if (data.formType == 'create') // not changed until page refresh
                alert('save the record');
            else if (data.formType == 'edit')
                _connectPrinter(data);
        }
    });
 }
```

After saving record the `data.formType` changed as 'edit', but inside the event value not changed until page refresh.

Comment: You need to reregister it with new value. As the previous value was in a closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://api.jquery.com/off/,

```
$('body').off('keydown').on('keydown', function (e) {
   // your code here
}
```

The .off() method removes registered values.